# Favourite button functionality in iOS Application

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uibutton

I have been working on iOS application and i got weird behaviour by my application.

**Scenario :**

I have a screen with 2 buttons. 1st button named as All Objects and 2nd button named is My Favourites Objects.

On click one of these button i will open a table view controller  with custom cell.
     each cell has button star that make it favourite. After that i press star and save the remoteID and 1 for favourite in Core data and in an other table but as i save query came back and check my favourites it's showing nothing. On that button i have write code for get all objects from favourite button.

**Code on Favourite Button IBAction Method**

```
NSEntityDescription *sessionFavourite = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext]];
Favourite *favor =(Favourite *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:sessionFavourite insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext]];
favor.remoteId = [sd remoteId];
favor.isFav    = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSError *error;
if (![[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

**Code In View Did Load of ViewController for my favourites objects**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
favList = [result mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"Count(%lu)",(unsigned long)[favList count]);
```

**Count is Zero here**

Comment: First check if the favorite item is getting saved in the database, if not then probably that's the place where you need to fix some code. OR if record is getting saved in database please revisit your query to fetch records from core data. Also please show us some code without which we can provide you assumptions n not point where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and i do not see any flaw here, what i am eager to know is about the macro APP_DELEGATE, here's the updated code which is motivated from your code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

AppDelegate *appDel =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
currentContext = appDel.managedObjectContext;

[self storeFavourites];
[self getFavourites];

}
```

// store favorites method

```
- (void)storeFavourites{
NSEntityDescription *sessionFavourite = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:currentContext];

Favourite *favor =(Favourite *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:sessionFavourite insertIntoManagedObjectContext:currentContext];
favor.remoteId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]; // assuming this is integer as you have used some [sd remoteId]
favor.isFav = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]; 

NSError *error;
if (![currentContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

The save method works fine as i have verified this in the application home directory, now adding the fetch method

```
- (void)getFavourites{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:currentContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [currentContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)result.count);
}
```

To resolve this at your end please add debugger and check if the managedObjectContext has memory, many times this is the common issue due to which data is not fetched / added.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it's working and more over i got the strategy of creating functions.
Thanks once again.